# Wordpress redirects to 404 when updating post

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have no issues adding a new post, but when I make changes to an existing post then click "Update", it loads `http://www.myexample.com/wp-admin/post.php` which shows the 404 error. My permalinks are set to `http://www.myexample.com/%postname%/`. I've tried:

- Changing file permissions on `.htaccess` at the root of my server's `public_html` folder
- Reverting to default theme
- Deactivating all plugins
- Setting `$is_apache` equal to `1` in `wp-includes/vars.php`
- Reverting to an older version of Wordpress (3.8 => 3.7.1)
- Re-installing Wordpress

Based on many Google searches, it seems this problem has existed for a long time for many users, but there do not appear to be any solid solutions.

Does anyone have any ideas? Could it be an issue with my web host (Namecheap)?

Thank you for your time

EDIT: Here are some of my version numbers. PHP 5.3.27, Apache 2.2.25

Here's what my current `.htaccess` file contains:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

EDIT: I'm able to 'Quick Edit' my posts, but the 404 is reached through the normal Edit interface.

Comment: I have nearly the same problem. Did you get a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This might seem silly, but visit the permalinks settings page inside your admin. That resets some of the permalink data and has cleared up odd issues like this for me in the past.

Comment: I've been visiting the Permalinks page frequently while attempting to troubleshoot this issue. This does not seem to fix my problems. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not rewriting issue. Edit post page is sending data to post.php by post method. Remaing data (?post= ... &action=edit&message= ...)  will be retrieved  by wp-includes/functions.php from '_wp_http_referer' which is send as a hidden input field. 
The problem, in my opinion, is caused by wrong post numbers while opening the post. Can be caused by wrong records in database. To check if I'm right, try open manually created url's with correct post no.

Comment: How are wrong records being set in the database? What do you mean "correct post number"? What is your solution to prevent this issue?

Comment: In my case it was after clients manual edit by phpMyadmin. To be honest I'm not sure what was done, but i had to rewrite post id's. By checking with correct post number I mean check id of existing post in sql, enter  /wp-admin/post.php?post= **postid** &action=edit&message=1 if no 404 appears then you can focus on error of post id's in database.